# menu for responsive design

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i want to make my website responsive i use html5, css3, javascript and jquery
i want my menu to be responsive and i have a problem in my css

- PRÉSENTATION
- OFFRES
- PRODUITS
- RÉFÉRENCE
- CONTACT

Menu

```
nav {
    height: 40px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #455868;
    font-size: 11pt;
    font-family: 'PT Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    position: relative;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #283744;
}
nav ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 600px;
    height: 40px;
}
nav li {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
}
nav a {
    color: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 40px;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #283744;
}
nav li a {
    border-right: 1px solid #576979;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
}
nav li:last-child a {
    border-right: 0;
}
nav a:hover, nav a:active {
    background-color: #8c99a4;
}
nav a#pull {
    display: none;
}

/*Styles for screen 600px and lower*/
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    nav { 
        height: auto;
    }
    nav ul {
        width: 100%;
        display: block;
        height: auto;
    }
    nav li {
        width: 50%;
        float: left;
        position: relative;
    }
    nav li a {
        border-bottom: 1px solid #576979;
        border-right: 1px solid #576979;
    }
    nav a {
        text-align: left;
        width: 100%;
        text-indent: 25px;
    }
}

/*Styles for screen 515px and lower*/
@media only screen and (max-width : 480px) {
    nav {
        border-bottom: 0;
    }
    nav ul {
        display: none;
        height: auto;
    }
    nav a#pull {
        display: block;
        background-color: #283744;
        width: 100%;
        position: relative;
    }
    nav a#pull:after {
        content:"";
        background: url('nav-icon.png') no-repeat;
        width: 30px;
        height: 30px;
        display: inline-block;
        position: absolute;
        right: 15px;
        top: 10px;
    }
}

/*Smartphone*/
@media only screen and (max-width : 320px) {
    nav li {
        display: block;
        float: none;
        width: 100%;
    }
    nav li a {
        border-bottom: 1px solid #576979;
    }
}
```

i have a problem in menu can someone help me to fix it.

Comment: You didnt even mention the problem. You just throw some code.

Comment: the menu not responsive

Answer (score 0):

Please try to put all on this jsfiddle and show us what's wrong for u.

```css
nav {
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #455868;
  font-size: 11pt;
  font-family: 'PT Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #283744;
}
nav ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 600px;
  height: 40px;
}
nav li {
  display: inline;
  float: left;
}
nav a {
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #283744;
}
nav li a {
  border-right: 1px solid #576979;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}
nav li:last-child a {
  border-right: 0;
}
nav a:hover,
nav a:active {
  background-color: #8c99a4;
}
nav a#pull {
  display: none;
}
/*Styles for screen 600px and lower*/

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  nav {
    height: auto;
  }
  nav ul {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    height: auto;
  }
  nav li {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
  }
  nav li a {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #576979;
    border-right: 1px solid #576979;
  }
  nav a {
    text-align: left;
    width: 100%;
    text-indent: 25px;
  }
}
/*Styles for screen 515px and lower*/

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  nav {
    border-bottom: 0;
  }
  nav ul {
    display: none;
    height: auto;
  }
  nav a#pull {
    display: block;
    background-color: #283744;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
  }
  nav a#pull:after {
    content: "";
    background: url('nav-icon.png') no-repeat;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 15px;
    top: 10px;
  }
}
/*Smartphone*/

@media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {
  nav li {
    display: block;
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
  }
  nav li a {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #576979;
  }
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>PRÉSENTATION</li>
    <li>OFFRES</li>
    <li>PRODUITS</li>
    <li>RÉFÉRENCE</li>
    <li>CONTACT</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```